# Passing Type parameter to generic in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic class `ValueCriterion` that take another class type as parameter. Following code works fine.

```
new ValueCriterion<,CrashDetected>(0));
```

Where `CrashDetected` is a class.

But when I get the type of the `CrashDetected` class using the following code.

```
Type myType = Type.GetType("NetworkDB." + "CrashDetected");
```

and pass `myType` to `ValueCriterion`, the compiler gives me the following error:

```
new ValueCriterion<,myType>(0));
```

> Error 1   Using the generic type requires 1 type arguments.

I will highly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MakeGenericType` method to create a generic type using a `Type` instance:

```
var type = typeof(ValueCriterion<>).MakeGenericType(myType);

var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, 0);
```

Comment: Selman22... you are great. My problem is half solved now. So I can create object and pass them. How about If i need to pass type as paramenter Execution.Wait<CrashDetected>

Comment: @Tom you should get the generic method Wait with Reflection then use MakeGenericMethod and pass the type.